# Using webpack [request] magic comment is bundling together dynamic modules as one

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-4, dynamic-import

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
{
  path: '/home',
  name: 'home',
  component: () => import(  /* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */
    `@/views/Home.vue`)
},
{
  path: '/about',
  name: 'about',
  component: () => import(  /* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */
    `@/views/About.vue`)



}
  ]
})
```

Expected out put in chunks
About-vue.de9bf8b8.js   app.cb7314dd.js chunk-vendors.cc2e3269.js
Home-vue.de9bf8b8.js.map

But actual result is
[request].de9bf8b8.js   app.cb7314dd.js chunk-vendors.cc2e3269.js

When I omit the [request] or try with a function like

```
function getComp(fileName)

{

console.log(‘func called’)

return ()=>import(/* webpackChunkName: “[request]” */ @/views/${fileName}.vue)

}
```

in this approach it works , it also works fine when i omit the [request] but the my bundles are difficult to manage and debug without proper names

Comment: It's a little confusing what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to bundle different modules together (as stated in title), or to give them meaningful names?

Comment: You have `/* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */` so why are you surprised you are getting a chunk named `[request]`? That is the [expected behavior](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments).

Comment: I want chunks with meaningful names , but adding names leads to them being bundled together

Comment: The first code block works as expected. But since you managed to make it work with the function and the `[request]` in your second code block, what is the issue now?

Comment: In the first one I want 2 chunks but with the corresponding names as file name , Instead that i get is a single chunk names as request which is not what the request keyword is for

Answer (score 1):

The magic comment isn't dynamically replaced. And anywhere the comment name is used will group assets into a single chunk by that name

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for proper names, use the name of your component instead of `[request]` as chunk name.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'home',
      component: () => import(  /* webpackChunkName: "Home" */ `@/views/Home.vue`)
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: () => import(  /* webpackChunkName: "About" */ `@/views/About.vue`)
    }
  ]
});
```

The `[request]` placeholder is intended for importing files based on conditions. Suppose
you have multiple locales as follows.

```
> locales/en.js
> locales/bn.js
```

Then you are going to import one of these based on user's preference. Then you import it
as follows:

```
const lang = "en";
import(/* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */ `./locales/${lang}`).then(lang_module => {
    // do something with english locale
});
```

When webpack builds them, it saves both locales as their original file names. You can
also use `locale-[request]` to save them as `locale-en` and `locale-bn` respectively.

But when you know for sure which file you are going to import, why use `[request]`? Just use the name you know already. See [magic comments](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments) for more info.

Comment: I understood that , but for files I know also I thought this will be easier to use

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`magic-comments-loader`](https://github.com/morganney/magic-comments-loader).

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: ['magic-comments-loader']
    }
  ]
}
```

For your specific example, the **default** configuration would provide chunk names like `@-views-Home` and `@-views-About`.

Of course you don't have to use the default configuration. You can provide configuration based on the magic comment you're targeting. In this case, for `webpackChunkName`, you could use `basename`:

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'magic-comments-loader',
        options: {
          webpackChunkName: {
            options: {
              basename: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To get chunk names of `Home` and `About`.

You could also provide a function to control the chunk name more dynamically:

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'magic-comments-loader',
        options: {
          webpackChunkName: (modulePath, importPath) => {
            return 'custom-chunk-name'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The function is passed the absolute file path to the module using a dynamic import (`modulePath`), and the specifier value used in the import (`importPath`).